# php contact form not sending mail after validation

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, email

I'm using a contact form for my website, which I validate and then email to myself, the validation is working correctly and it emails me if the user enters all the details correctly first time. However if the user enters incorrect data, then corrects it and hits send again, it won't send an email, below is the form and PHP code I have so far.

HTML code for contact form

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
<fieldset>

<label for="name">Name:<span class="star">*</span></label> <br />
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" maxlength="50" required />
<label for="email">Email:<span class="star">*</span></label> <br />
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" maxlength="100" required />
<label for="number">Telephone: </label><input type="tel" name="number" id="number" placeholder="Enter your phone number" maxlength="12" />
<label for="message">Message:<span class="star">*</span></label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" cols="54" rows="5" required></textarea>

<p class="small"><span class="star">*</span>&nbsp; Denotes a required field </p>

<input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="Send" />

</fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP code for sending the form

```
    function fix_string($var)
{
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $var = stripslashes($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    return $var;
}

{
    $details = array('name' => fix_string($_POST['name']),
            'email' => fix_string($_POST['email']),
            'number' => fix_string($_POST['number']),
            'message' => fix_string($_POST['message']));
}

$send = $_POST['send'];
$message = "";

 foreach ($details as $field => $detail)
    $message .= $field . ": " . $detail . "<br />";

$to = "smokey.12345@hotmail.co.uk";
$subject = "Website contact form";
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "/r/n");
$headers = "From ". $details['email'];

function trim_value(&$value)
{
    $value = trim($value);
}

array_walk($details, 'trim_value');

if ($send)
{
    foreach ($details as $field => $detail)
    {
        if (empty($detail) && $field!='number')
            echo "<p class='error'>Please fill in the required field: " . ucfirst($field) . "<br /></p>";

    }
}
else
{
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "<p class='success'>Mail was sent successfully</p>";
}
```

Comment: its kind of hard to say what is happening when that is only a snippet of your code, is this code running on your local machine or actually on the server because in most local enviroments php's mail function will not work, could you post the whole code please

Comment: need more info, cant see where your mail variables are defined

Comment: Have added all the PHP code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

In order for the code to work on the same page, you need to set the action to `action=""`

Otherwise, you need to use two pages. One for your form and one for `contact.php` which is your handler. I suggest you use two pages, but here is a version that will work inside one page.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['send'])) {

function fix_string($var)
{
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $var = stripslashes($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    return $var;
}

    $details = array('name' => fix_string($_POST['name']),
            'email' => fix_string($_POST['email']),
            'number' => fix_string($_POST['number']),
            'message' => fix_string($_POST['message']));

function trim_value(&$value)
{
    $value = trim($value);
}

array_walk($details, 'trim_value');

    foreach ($details as $field => $detail)

    {
        if (empty($detail) && $field!='number')

            die("<p class='error'>Please fill in the required field: " . ucfirst($field) . "<br /></p>");

    }

$message = "";
 foreach ($details as $field => $detail)
    $message .= $field . ": " . $detail . "\n";

$send = $_POST['send'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$to = "smokey.12345@hotmail.co.uk";
$subject = "Website contact form";

$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "<p class='success'>Mail was sent successfully</p>";


exit;

} // closing brace for if(isset($_POST['send'])) {

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="post">
<fieldset>

<label for="name">Name:<span class="star">*</span></label> <br />
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" maxlength="50"  />
<label for="email">Email:<span class="star">*</span></label> <br />
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" maxlength="100"  />
<label for="number">Telephone: </label><input type="tel" name="number" id="number" placeholder="Enter your phone number" maxlength="12" />
<label for="message">Message:<span class="star">*</span></label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" cols="54" rows="5" ></textarea>

<p class="small"><span class="star">*</span>&nbsp; Denotes a required field </p>

<input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="Send" />

</fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

### Original answer

This line is not properly formatted.

```
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "/r/n");
```

change it to:

```
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
```

You need to use `\` instead of `/`

### EDIT

The only way I could get your form to work, is to add a `die` function.

Try this now:

```
<?php

function fix_string($var)
{
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $var = stripslashes($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    return $var;
}

    $details = array('name' => fix_string($_POST['name']),
            'email' => fix_string($_POST['email']),
            'number' => fix_string($_POST['number']),
            'message' => fix_string($_POST['message']));

function trim_value(&$value)
{
    $value = trim($value);
}

array_walk($details, 'trim_value');

    foreach ($details as $field => $detail)

    {
        if (empty($detail) && $field!='number')

            die("<p class='error'>Please fill in the required field: " . ucfirst($field) . "<br /></p>");

    }

$message = "";
 foreach ($details as $field => $detail)
    $message .= $field . ": " . $detail . "\n";

$send = $_POST['send'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$to = "smokey.12345@hotmail.co.uk";
$subject = "Website contact form";

$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "<p class='success'>Mail was sent successfully</p>";


exit;

?>
```

Comment: I changed the wordwrap bit, but if I change it to isset, the validation no longer works

Comment: Then just leave `if ($send)` the way it is.

Comment: Another thing I just noticed is this line `if (empty($detail) && $field!='number')` which in a way doesn't make sense. It's checking to see if it doesn't equal `number`

Comment: What it does it check that the field is not empty and its not the number field as that field isn't required, and all the others are

Comment: Ok, this line `$headers = "From ". $details['email'];` seems to be doing some funny  tricks. Headers are a tricky thing. I suggest you use standard header formatting. I'm testing your code now and even when I enter all the fields, am not getting anything back. Will test with proper headers and let you know.

Comment: Your form's headers are a problem, plus since your are using `<br/>` tags, needs to be sent as HTML, that's another issue.

Comment: Ok, I didn't give up so fast. Try my edit now. It's the best I could do and it works.

Comment: The code works and it fixes the original problem, so thanks. However when I put the PHP code before the form HTML it doesn't display the form at all. Maybe has something to do with die or exit commands.

Comment: @Harry12345 That is because you have all the code in one page and the action needs to be set to `action=""` and not `contact.php` in order for it to work. If you use 2 seperate pages, then it will work. One for the form and one for the `contact.php` PHP handler.

Comment: Hold on, I'm looking into it. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer with a method to use on a single page. Your original question pointed to `contact.php` as being a seperate page. See details in answer.

Comment: I have to mention that, the function will execute right away (if used in a single page) if there is no `if(isset...`, and that is why it's better to use it in 2 different files. Just thought you would like to know why it reacted that way.

Comment: Ok thanks, the reason I wanted to use it in the same page was so that I could display the error/success message on the same page as the form, and I don't know how to do that when using an external file

Comment: You're quite welcome. Another way to do that would be to use Ajax.